# Restricting admin from destroying own account using cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, restrict

Here is a snippet of my code from my ability class

```
if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
      can :destroy, :all if != current_user
```

I am sure that you can figure out what I am trying to do here. I realize that destroy is included in manage and I am repeating myself there. Any suggestions?

**EDIT** Yjerem's answer was the correct one and I just changed it to fit my code. This is what it looks like.

```
 if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
      cannot :destroy, User, :id => user.id
```

As Yjerem also said, in cancan, ability precedence states that the ability defined lower down trump the ones over them so an admin can manage all except what is defined under it using the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [Ability Precedence](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence), there's an example there just for you!

Basically what you want is the `cannot` method:

```
if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
      cannot :destroy, User, :id => current_user.id
```

Because the `cannot` rule is below the more general one, it overrides it.

Comment: I don't think the `current_user` is accessible from within the Ability class.

Comment: I was looking all over for something in their documentation. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @feelnoway `current_user` here is the object passed into the Ability class (it's the same thing as `user` in your answer)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this (assuming you have an Account/User model):

```
def initialize(user)
  ...

  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
    can :destroy, Account do |account|
      account.user != user # admin can destroy all Accounts/Users except his own
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: While I got no errors in my text editor for this. 

if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
      can :destroy, User do |u| 
        u.id != user.id
     end

It still was giving me errors. I am going to take a look at the precedence documentation real quick.